# checking if column exists and renaming it in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to rename the column name of table in postgresql.

I tried:

```
do $$
begin
if exists(select "xyz" from table_1) 
then alter table table_1 rename "xyz" to "abc"
end if;
end $$
```

The problem is that column "xyz" does not exist in table_1 and im getting error for it.

But I specifically need to find if column "xyz" exist and then rename it.

Is there any way which allows me to use query like `(select * from table_1 where column_name="xyz")` because this way the 'exists' might return true is "xyz" is in table or return false otherwise.
If there is any other way to check the existence of a column and then renaming it in POSTGRESQL I am  open to suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

yes , here is one way :

```
do $$
begin
if exists (
   select 1 
   from information_schema.columns 
   where table_schema='my_schema' 
   and table_name='table_1' 
   and column_name='xyz'
)
alter table table_1 rename "xyz" to "abc"
end if;
end $$
```